# Issue too access CDS data with xarray

Tags: python-xarray, cds.copernicus

I have an issue for few days with xarray and CDS.

### The issue

I download data from CDS Copernicus using this link

```py
import cdsapi

c = cdsapi.Client()

c.retrieve(
    'reanalysis-era5-single-levels',
    {
        'product_type': 'reanalysis',
        'variable': '2m_temperature',
        'year': '2017',
        'month': '01',
        'day': '01',
        'time': [
            '00:00', '01:00', '02:00',
            '03:00', '04:00', '05:00',
            '06:00', '07:00', '08:00',
            '09:00', '10:00', '11:00',
            '12:00', '13:00', '14:00',
            '15:00', '16:00', '17:00',
            '18:00', '19:00', '20:00',
            '21:00', '22:00', '23:00',
        ],
        'format': 'netcdf',
    },
    'download.nc')
```

and then I open the file with:

```py
file = 'download.nc'
ds = xarray.open_mfdataset(file, engine="netcdf4")
```

However, the data are not correct.

Here you can see an example for 2017-01-01 12:00

[image: Raw values]

[image: Raw values displayed in matlplot/cartopy]

To create the plot, I use this method:

```py
def scalarPlot(
    ax,
    data: Dataset,
    variable: List[str],
    geoPosition: Optional[Tuple[float, float, float, float]],
    cmap: Colormap,
    normalizer: Normalize,
    x: str = "longitude",
    y: str = "latitude",
    transform: crs.Projection = crs.PlateCarree(),
    **kwargs,
):
    data[variable[0]].plot(
        ax=ax,
        x=x,
        y=y,
        transform=transform,
        cmap=cmap,
        norm=normalizer,
        cbar_kwargs={
            "label": FigureUtils.getLabel(data=data, variable=variable),
            "boundaries": numpy.linspace(normalizer.vmin, normalizer.vmax, 250),
            "ticks": numpy.linspace(normalizer.vmin, normalizer.vmax, 11),
            "orientation": "vertical",
            "shrink": 0.5,
            "extend": "both",
        },
        **kwargs,
    )
```

Data is provide in a dataset and I use the `xarray.plot()` method to display the data. However, the issue seems to come from the reading of the downloaded file (see raw data screenshot).

When I use the CDS toolbox, data is shown correctly

[image: Raw data shown using CDS toolbox]

### My setup

The current libraries I installed are:

```
xarray: 2022.3.0
pandas: 1.4.3
numpy: 1.23.1
scipy: 1.8.1
netCDF4: 1.6.0
pydap: None
h5netcdf: None
h5py: None
Nio: None
zarr: None
cftime: 1.6.1
nc_time_axis: None
PseudoNetCDF: None
rasterio: None
cfgrib: 0.9.10.1
iris: None
bottleneck: None
dask: 2022.7.0
distributed: None
matplotlib: 3.5.2
cartopy: 0.20.3
seaborn: None
numbagg: None
fsspec: 2022.5.0
cupy: None
pint: 0.19.2
sparse: None
setuptools: 59.6.0
pip: 22.1.2
conda: None
pytest: None
IPython: None
sphinx: None
```

### Questions

Is there a known issue with this library ?

Few weeks ago, CDS experienced an important disturbance. But it has been solved.
https://confluence.ecmwf.int/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=278543465
Does the issue impact also something else ?

Best regards,
Thomas

Comment: you're plotting the data from download.nc using CDS toolbox, or is this pulling directly from the online archive? Can you show the code you use to generate the xarray plot?

Comment: The incorrect plot is from xarray.plot() method using the CDS archives I download.
The correct plot is from the CDS toolbox online.

I upload my first post with the method I used to plot.